# Unable to import lens library

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I installed haskell lens library. In ghci I try to run

```
λ> import Control.Lens
```

and it says -

```
<no location info>:
    Could not find module ‘Control.Lens’
    Perhaps you meant Control.Seq (from parallel-3.2.0.4)
```

I ran ghc-pkg list to list the installed packages and it does show -

```
lens-4.6.0.1
```

I am using GHC 7.8.3 on Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: Have you started that GHCi session before or after installing the package? Does the module load in a fresh session?

Comment: @leftaroundabout I started the GHCi session after installing the package, in a new terminal window.

Comment: And you're sure `ghc-pkg`/`cabal-install` and `ghci` actually use the same compiler version? Do other cabal installs work?

Comment: @leftaroundabout Yes, they use the same compiler version. Other cabal installs seem to work. Somehow this seems to be related to Template Haskell also.

Comment: what `ghc-pkg check` says?

Comment: @ДМИТРИЙМАЛИКОВ a couple of warnings related to haddock-html and haddock-interfaces but nothing else.

Comment: Are you using sandboxes?

Comment: @mhwombat no i am not using sandboxes.